# Embed Bockeh plot in Html using python and flask - blank plot

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm having some issues when I try to embed a Bockeh plot in a html page created using python and flask. I'm trying to plot the data from a pandas dataframe, and embed it using `json_item` to render it into a `<div>`.

The problem is that I don't get the graphic plot, but a bunch of json text, and when I try to plot it from the python shell, for debugging, the plot appears blank without data.

I have done what they say on the documentation but there's not much and I'm not an expert at all, maybe I'm missing something... Hope you can help me guys, if you need more information just let me know.

Here's the python main file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from customfile import getDF
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.embed import json_item
from jinja2 import Template
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

#Read the main html file and use Template function
hh = open(os.path.join(directory,"templates\\home.html"))
page = Template(hh.read())

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return page.render(resources=CDN.render())

@app.route('/plot',methods=['POST'])
def plot():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        #Start pulling data from form input
        a= request.form['a'] #Argument1
        b= request.form['b'] #Argument2
        c= request.form['c'] #Name of dataframe column I want to plot
        
        #call a function that return the dataframe (it has one index and multiple columns)
        #this is the section I try for debugging in python shell

        df = getDF(str(a),int(b))
        
        source = ColumnDataSource(df)
        
        p = figure()
        
        p.line(x='index',y=str(c),source=source) #show(p) --> blank plot

        return json.dumps(json_item(p,"myplot"))
    else:
        return page.render(resources=CDN.render())
```

And here is the main HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" shrink-to-fit="no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>APIBEX-35</title>
        <link 
            rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css"
        />

        <!-- Found in other post that I have to put the resources here (CDN) -->
        {{ resources }}

    </head>
    
    <body>

        <div id="Plot tool" class="container">

            <form action="/plot" method="POST">

                <!-- ...Here some labels and fields to fill the form data... -->

                <input type="submit" value="Plot" id="plot_btn" />
            </form>

        </div>

        <div id="myplot"></div>

        <script>
            fetch('/plot')
                .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
                .then(function(item) { return Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item); })
        </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already solved, just needed to do a couple things.

First, the template had to be `{{ resources|safe }}` instead of `{{ resources }}`.

Second, I used `components` from bokeh.embed module like this: `script, div = components(p)` and render them also in the template `{{ script|safe }}` and `{{ div|safe }}`

Finally I also needed to clean the browser cache.